# Plone 4: Dexterity objects not added to catalog

Tags: plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

I'm developing a new add-on for my Plone site, using Dexterity-based objects now. It seems, my object types are not added to my `portal_catalog`.

For Archetypes-based portal types, I found [this section on the Catalog page](https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/catalog.html#map-an-catalog-for-an-new-type) ([Plone 4 version](https://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/plone/searching_and_indexing/catalog.html#map-an-catalog-for-an-new-type)). Dexterity is not mentioned there.

How are Dexterity-based types registered for automatic addition to the catalog?  Is there some behavior to use?  Do I need to register my types using a migration step?

Answer (score 2):

If your content type is built on Dexterity, the objects are cataloged. You may prove that to yourself by visiting portal_catalog/Indexes/portal_type tab. Choose the "Browse" tab and look for your content type.

So, why do you think your type is not cataloged? If you don't have any fields matching the indexes, then you can't find items by that index. For example, if you have no "title" or "description" fields, the item will not show up when you search via the main search form.

The Dublin metadata and basic metadata behaviors add those fields. If you don't want to use those behaviors, you've either got to add the fields individually -- making sure the ids match -- or you've got to use a package like collective.dexteritytextindexer to choose the searchable fields.

Comment: What I did: I went to my `portal_catalog`, opened checked the `Catalog` tab, and `Set Filter` to each of my Dexterity-based types. No hits. Is this what you mean?